# How to close split window / adjacent editor - Xcode 4

Tags: xcode4, editor, window, split

I've managed,  by playing around with the menus in Xcode 4, to open a window in an adjacent editor (Navigate, open in adjacent editor). Unfortunately, I'm having trouble figuring out how to close that window. How do you do that?

Answer (score 19):

```
Cmd+Enter
```

or `View -> Standard Editor -> Show Standard Editor`

Answer (score 11):

I fixed this by going to 'view > editor > standard' and this reset the view to the standard one window view. I have yet to figure out why the x in the upper right corner of the new window is grayed out. Not a perfect solution, but a solution.

Answer (score 3):

There's a close button in the upper right corner of an assistant editor to close the editor.

[image]

The first assistant editor doesn't have buttons to add and close editors, which can be confusing.

Comment: Yes, I saw that - but it's grayed out for some reason.

Comment: The View menu has menu items to remove assistant editors and reset the editor, but you have to have 3 or more editors open to enable the menu items.

Answer (score 0):

I am using XCode 13.41.  There is an "X" icon at the top left corner of the editor view. (You can hover on it to reveal what it does). Click on the X to close the editor.

Answer (score 0):

View -> Hide Code Review (Show Code Review)

or

⌥ + ⇧ + ⌘ + ⏎ (But on my mac this works when it is closed and I want to open it and doesn't work vise versa)